# function which returns HttpClient response in Angular5?

Tags: angular, apache-httpclient-4.x

I followed the "Tour of heroes" Angular tutorial, and could apply the same mechanisms to retreive a list of items from a webservice and display it in a table.

Now I'm writing a function which call a webservice to check credentials. This webservice returns one line: `{ "msg": "Hello username" }`

**login.component.html**:

```
[...]
<a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" (click)="onLogIn(loginForm)"> Log in </a>
[...]
```

**login.component.ts**:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router,
                private loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onLogIn(loginForm: any) {
        let authResponse = this.loginService.check_credentials(loginForm.controls.login.value, loginForm.controls.password.value);
        console.log(authResponse)
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
    }
```

**login.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private wsLoginUrl = '/api/check_login';

    wsResponse;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    check_credentials(login: string, password: string): string {
        this.getResponse().subscribe(response => this.wsResponse = response);
        this.getResponse().subscribe(response => console.log(response));
        console.log(this.wsResponse);
        return "ok" 
    }

    getResponse() { 
        return this.http.get(this.wsLoginUrl);
    }    
}
```

The console output is :

```
undefined                          login.service.ts:43:12
ok                                 login.component.ts:25:8
Object { msg: "Hello username" }   login.service.ts:34:53
```

Since 'ok' is before the webservice response, I guess once the `subscribe(...)` is done the function code continues. Then, when the webservice responds, the subscribe code is executed : `console.log(response)` and `this.wsResponse = response`.

How can I make a function which will wait for the webservice response ?

I tried different methods, using map() or other SO answers, yet I can't find how I can do this.

---

Updated code, thanks to Rubén Soler's answer now it works :

**login.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable }              from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private wsLoginUrl = '/api/check_login';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    async checkCredentials(login: string, password: string) {
        try {
            let response = await this.getResponse().toPromise();
            return response;
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }

    getResponse() { 
        return this.http.get(this.wsLoginUrl);
    }

}
```

**login.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { Router }                 from '@angular/router';
import { routerTransition }       from '../router.animations';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService }           from './login.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
    animations: [routerTransition()]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router,
                private loginService: LoginService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onLogIn(loginForm: any) {
        this.loginService.checkCredentials(loginForm.controls.login.value, loginForm.controls.password.value)
            .then((resp) => { 
                if (resp['msg'] == 'hello') {
                    console.log('Resp is ok')
                    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
                    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Resp is NOT ok')
                    //Other things...
                }
            } );
    }

}
```

Comment: call the function inside .subscribe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is working fine but you only needs to analyce your execution flow.

First print `undefined` because the first subscription is still waiting.

```
console.log(this.wsResponse);
```

Second prints ok because you `return 'ok'` (sincronously) in the `check_credentials`  function, and prints in the component when you are using it.

```
let authResponse = this.loginService.check_credentials(loginForm.controls.login.value, loginForm.controls.password.value);
console.log(authResponse)
```

After that the subscribers get the response and execute the success function in `check_credentials` asyncronously and prints `{ msg: "Hello username" }` :

```
this.getResponse().subscribe(response => this.wsResponse = response);
this.getResponse().subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

If you wants to await the response in the `check_credentials` function you can transform the observable into promise  and use `async/await` like this (login.service.ts):

```
async check_credentials(login: string, password: string): string {
       try {           
             let response = await this.getResponse().toPromise();
             this.wsResponse = response;    
             return response
           } catch(e) {
             console.error(e);
           }
}
```

login.component.ts:

```
onLogIn(loginForm: any) {
      this.loginService.check_credentials(loginForm.controls.login.value, loginForm.controls.password.value)
        .then((res) => console.log(authResponse))
}
```

You can read more about that here: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

and here https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Comment: Thanks a lot Rubén, it all works now. I updated my code according to your answer. A small typo: `.then((res) => console.log(res))` . I appreciated that you included some try/catch in your code.